# SonarQube 6.5 failed at "Start pointer [line=58, lineOffset=36] should be before end pointer..."

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, sonarqube

Our `.Net` project is using `SonarQube 6.5` with `Jenkins`. It worked fine until some days ago. Sonar failed during scanning. I found the source file causing the problem but can not find why (build still success).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6ybZ.png)

This line causes Sonar stop

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Start pointer [line=58,
>   lineOffset=36] should be before end pointer [line=58, lineOffset=36]
>     at
>   org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)

Temporary I exclude this file for project running.
Anyone can help me what the problem is and how to fix this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have upgraded Sonar to ver 6.7, Jenkins 2.73.3. This error automatically was removed. No need to change code.